# Call onClick in custom control

Tags: android, onclick, touch-event

I created a component having inherited it from View. How I can call function set in property (Android:OnClick) in my event of OnTouchEvent?

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use a special method to simulate button click.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()